# Convert matrix to 3-column table ('reverse pivot', 'unpivot', 'flatten', 'normalize')

Tags: excel, matrix, pivot-table, unpivot, powerquery

I need to convert the Excel matrix `FIRST` in the table `LATER`:

**FIRST**:

```
    P1  P2  P3  P4
F1  X
F2  X   X
F3      X       X
F4      X   X
```

**LATER**:

```
F   P   VALUE
F1  P1  X
F1  P2
F1  P3
F1  P4
F2  P1  X
F2  P2  X
F2  P3
F2  P4
F3  P1
F3  P2  X
F3  P3
F3  P4  X
F4  P1
F4  P2  X
F4  P3  X
F4  P4
```

Comment: A simple google would have fetched you your [answer](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/701104-convert-matrix-worrk-sheet-flat-file.html)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

### To “reverse pivot”, “unpivot” or “flatten”:

1. For Excel 2003: Activate any cell in your summary table and choose Data - PivotTable and PivotChart Report:

   [image: SO20541905 first example]

For later versions access the Wizard with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>.

For Excel for Mac 2011, it's <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> ([See here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Consolidate-multiple-data-sources-in-a-PivotTable-8f476919-40b3-4133-9870-26f4d9f21ad6)).

2. Select *Multiple consolidation ranges* and click <kbd>Next</kbd>.

   [image: SO20541905 second example]
3. In “Step 2a of 3”, choose *I will create the page fields* and click <kbd>Next</kbd>.

   [image: SO20541905 third example]
4. In “Step 2b of 3” specify your summary table range in the **Range** field (A1:E5 for the sample data) and click <kbd>Add</kbd>, then <kbd>Next</kbd>.

   [image: SO20541905 fourth example]
5. In “Step 3 of 3”, select a location for the pivot table (the existing sheet should serve, as the PT is only required temporarily):

   [image: SO20541905 fifth example]
6. Click <kbd>Finish</kbd> to create the pivot table:

   [image: SO20541905 sixth example]
7. Drill down (ie double-click) on the intersect of the Grand Totals (here Cell V7 or `7`):

   [image: SO20541905 seventh example]
8. The PT may now be deleted.
9. The resulting Table may be converted to a conventional array of cells by selecting **Table** in the Quick Menu (right-click in the Table) and **Convert to Range**.

---

There is a video on the same subject at [Launch Excel](http://www.launchexcel.com/pivot-table-flatten-crosstab/) which I consider excellent quality.

Comment: pnuts, this is really neat, the only down side being that if the data updates in the original table, it will not be automatically propagated to the new table. But, otherwise, a perfect solution!

Comment: ++ What can I say? Simply beautiful :)

Comment: This double click on the GrandTotal really is a hidden feature..  and a nice feature!

Comment: The ALT+D,P-Shortcut won't be available in non-English Excel versions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32115219/unpivot-an-excel-matrix-pivot-table/32116657#32116657 for a workaround.

Answer (score 31):

Another way to unpivot data without using VBA is with PowerQuery, a free add-in for Excel 2010 and higher, available here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379

Install and activate the Power Query add-in. Then follow these steps:

Add a column label to your data source and turn it into an Excel Table via Insert > Table or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>T</kbd>.

[image]

Select any cell in the table and on the Power Query ribbon click "From Table".

[image]

This will open the table in the Power Query Editor window.

[image]

Click the column header of the first column to select it. Then, on the **Transform** ribbon, click the **Unpivot Columns** drop-down and select **Unpivot other columns**.

For versions of Power Query that don't have the **Unpivot other columns** command, select all columns except the first one (using Shift-click on the column headers) and use the **Unpivot** command.

[image]

The result is a flat table. Click **Close and Load** on the Home ribbon and the data will be loaded onto a new Excel sheet.

[image]

Now to the good part. Add some data to your source table, for example

[image]

Click on the sheet with the Power Query result table and on the Data ribbon click **Refresh all**. You will see something like:

[image]

Power Query is not just a one-time transformation. It is repeatable and can be linked to dynamically changing data.

Comment: Thanks. Very simple and very powerful method. And best of all the data is dynamically linked!

Comment: Fabulous!  Thanks so much for this little tutorial. Saved probably hours of experimenting.

Answer (score 2):

All of the solutions so far involve VBA, PowerQuery, etc. which are great, but are "one-time" events.  To make it more dynamic, consider using INDEX(MATCH(...)).  This will allow for dynamic updates to the table.

[image]

Comment: This solution does have a traditional-Excel simplicity, but note that  teylyn’s solution, above, also allows for dynamic updates, and in a much more automated manner.

Answer (score 1):

The addition of the LET function & dynamic arrays allows for this non-VBA solution.

```
=LET(data,B2:E5,
     dataRows,ROWS(data),
     dataCols,COLUMNS(data),
     rowHeaders,OFFSET(data,0,-1,dataRows,1),
     colHeaders,OFFSET(data,-1,0,1,dataCols),
     dataIndex,SEQUENCE(dataRows*dataCols),
     rowIndex,MOD(dataIndex-1,dataRows)+1,
     colIndex,INT((dataIndex-1)/dataRows)+1,
     dataColumn, IF(INDEX(data,rowIndex,colIndex)="","",INDEX(data,rowIndex,colIndex)),
     unfiltered, CHOOSE({1,2,3},INDEX(rowHeaders,rowIndex),INDEX(colHeaders,colIndex), dataColumn),
     filtered, FILTER(unfiltered, dataColumn<>""),
     unfiltered)
```

This will show all items including those with blank data.  To eliminate the blanks change the last parameter to filtered.

Answer (score 0):

One more to add to the BoK.  This requires Excel 365. It unpivots B1:E5 by A1:A5.

```
=LET( unPivMatrix, B1:E5,
      byMatrix, A1:A5,
        upC, COLUMNS( unPivMatrix ),
        byC, COLUMNS( byMatrix ),
        dmxR, MIN( ROWS( unPivMatrix ), ROWS( byMatrix ) ) - 1,
        dmxSeq, SEQUENCE( dmxR ) + 1,
        upCells, dmxR * upC,
        upSeq, SEQUENCE( upCells,, 0 ),
        upHdr, INDEX( INDEX( unPivMatrix, 1, ),  1,  SEQUENCE( upC ) ),
        upBody, INDEX( unPivMatrix,  dmxSeq,  SEQUENCE( 1, upC ) ),
        byBody, INDEX( byMatrix,  dmxSeq,  SEQUENCE( 1, byC ) ),
        attr, INDEX( upHdr, MOD( upSeq, upC ) + 1 ),
        mux, INDEX( upBody, upSeq/upC + 1, MOD( upSeq, upC ) + 1 ),
        demux, IFERROR( INDEX(
                              IFERROR( INDEX( byBody,
                                              IFERROR( INT( SEQUENCE( upCells, byC,0 )/byC/upC ) + 1, MOD( upSeq, upC ) + 1 ),
                                                       SEQUENCE( 1, byC + 1 ) ),
                                        attr ),
                              upSeq + 1, SEQUENCE( 1, byC + 2 ) ),
                         mux ),
        FILTER(demux, mux<>"")
 )
```

> NB: the byMatrix can be a range with multiple columns and it will
> replicate the row values of the columns.  e.g. you could have byMatrix
> of A1:C5 and unPivMatrix of D1:H5 and it would replicate the A2:C5
> column values (ignoring A1).